# Ortools - VRP Allow for violation of constraint

Tags: or-tools, vehicle-routing

Is it possible in ortool's [vrp model](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing) to allow for violation of a constraint (sometimes called a soft-constraint)? E.g. Say each route should pick up a minimum volume of `x` in some unit, can I configure or-tools such that it will also return me tours subjected that this constraint is not always met?

Looking at the [penalties section](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties) I get the impression that when configured with `addDisjunction` or-tools will drop a visit if this makes a solution feasible. However, the problem I have at hand is quite the opposite: the visit shouldn't be dropped and instead, the constraint should be violated, subjected to some penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a "Volume" dimension and use on the end node:

```cpp
void RoutingDimension::SetCumulVarSoftLowerBound(int64 index, int64 lower_bound, int64 coefficient);
```

ref: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/858fa626959f7e386153af82756384b79f983b5a/ortools/constraint_solver/routing.h#L2236-L2249